# SQL Server 2012: Pivoting(?) fixed number of rows as columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, rows

I have a table called Car:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Brand] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
)
```

and one called Passenger:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Passenger](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CarID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
)
```

Containing the following data:

```
+----+------------+
| ID |   Brand    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Ford       |
|  2 | Audi       |
+----+------------+

+----+-------+------------+
| ID | CarID |    Name    |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 |     1 | Joe        |
|  2 |     1 | Jack       |
|  3 |     1 | Jim        |
|  4 |     2 | Bob        |
|  5 |     2 | Frank      |
+----+-------+------------+
```

Also, I have a limit for the number of passengers in a car = 5. (Business logic)

What I'd like to do is to display this data in a View table, like the following example:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID |   Brand    | Passenger1 | Passenger2 | Passenger3 | Passenger4 | Passenger5 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Ford       | Joe        | Jack       | Jim        | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | Audi       | Bob        | Frank      | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

So, there if there are less than 5 passengers, the rest of the columns is NULL, and we don't need to handle more than 5 passengers.

Ordering of passengers is not really needed, but `NULLs` must be at the end (e.g. `Frank, Bob, NULL, NULL, NULL is OK for Car ID 2, but Frank, NULL, NULL, Bob, NULL` is not.) If it is also possible to order the passengers, then I'd prefer to order them by their IDs.

How can I do this data transformation using *SQL Server 2012*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Pivot` operator to pivot the data

Use `Row_number` window function to generate the passenger number so the car without all the 5 passengers will have `NULL` values at the end

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT c.id,
                c.Brand,
                'Passenger'+ Cast(Row_number() OVER(partition BY c.id ORDER BY p.id) AS VARCHAR(50)) p_name,
                NAME
         FROM   [Car] c
                JOIN [Passenger] p
                  ON c.ID = p.CarID)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
       PIVOT (Max(NAME)
             FOR p_name IN(Passenger1,
                           Passenger2,
                           Passenger3,
                           Passenger4,
                           Passenger5 ))pv
ORDER  BY id
```

`Conditional Aggregate` method

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT c.id,
                c.Brand,
                'Passenger'+ Cast(Row_number() OVER(partition BY c.id ORDER BY p.id) AS VARCHAR(50)) p_name,
                NAME
         FROM   [Car] c
                JOIN Passenger p
                  ON c.ID = p.CarID)
SELECT id,
       Brand,
       [Passenger1]=Max(CASE WHEN p_name = 'Passenger1' THEN NAME END),
       [Passenger2]=Max(CASE WHEN p_name = 'Passenger2' THEN NAME END),
       [Passenger3]=Max(CASE WHEN p_name = 'Passenger3' THEN NAME END),
       [Passenger4]=Max(CASE WHEN p_name = 'Passenger4' THEN NAME END),
       [Passenger5]=Max(CASE WHEN p_name = 'Passenger5' THEN NAME END)
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY id,
          Brand
ORDER  BY id
```

**Result:**

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║   Brand    ║ Passenger1 ║ Passenger2 ║ Passenger3 ║ Passenger4 ║ Passenger5 ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ Ford       ║ Joe        ║ Jack       ║ Jim        ║ NULL       ║ NULL       ║
║  2 ║ Audi       ║ Bob        ║ Frank      ║ NULL       ║ NULL       ║ NULL       ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

We use row_num() over partition by card ID to get a constant seat number for the 5 positions add a P because I'm unsure if SQL server can have a column star with number and then pivot the data based on these 5 derived values.

```
Select brand, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5
FROM 
  (
  SELECT brand, name, 'P' & row_Number() Over (partition by CarID order by P.name) as PNum
  FROM car C
  INNER JOIN passenger P
    on C.CardID = P.CardID
  ) src
  PIVOT 
  (
    max(src.name)
    FOr pnum in ([P1],[P2],[P3],[P4],[P5])
  ) as PT
```